# Affine geometry and its basis

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I am trying to solve an exercise from the book "Permutation Groups" by J. Dixon and B. Mortimer, but, this is not a homework.

The affine geometry $AG_d(F)$ consists of points and affine subspaces constructed from the vector space $F^d$ of row vectors of dimension $d$ over the field $F$. The points of the geometry are the vectors of $F^d$ and the affine subspaces are the translates of the vector spaces of $F^d$. Thus if $W$ is a $k-$dimensional subspace of $F^d$, then $W+v=\{w+v:w\in W\}$. My question is about the following exercise, where $AGL_d(F)=\{t_{a,v}:u\mapsto ua+v \mid a \in GL_d(F),v\in F^d\}$:

[image]

For solving this exercise, if $\Sigma$ be the set of all affine bases, I defined the action of $AGL_d(F)$ on $\Sigma$ as follows:
$$B^{t_{A,v}}=\{(\alpha_0)A+v,\ldots, (\alpha_d)A+v \}$$ It is easy to see that this action is well-defined. Then I tried to prove that this action is transitive and regular, but despite my attempts, I could not.
Also, I tried to construct an example of an affine basis for $AG_d(F)$ to understand the definition better, but I could not too.

I appreciate for your help.

Comment: Here are some remarks that might be helpful. Firstly, all affine bases are of the form $\{v,v+v_1,v+v_2,\ldots,v+v_d\}$, where $v \in F^d$ and $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_d\}$ is a basis of $F^d$. Secondly, the question is not really correct, because ${\rm AGL}_d(F)$ is regular on the set of ordered affine bases rather than on the set of unordered affine bases, which the wording seems to imply. This problem is really just an extension of the fact that ${\rm GL}_d(F)$ is regular on the set of ordered bases of $F^d$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thank you so much because of your helpful hint. I can see that your mentioned example is an affine basis but is it easy to prove that all the affine bases are of such form? Also, did you mean that $AGL_d(F)$ is not transitive on the set of unordered bases too?

Comment: It is transitive on the set of unordered bases but not regular. A set $\{v_0,\ldots,v_d\}$ of $d+1$ vectors that was not of that form would be contained in the $(d-1)$-dimensional subspace $v_0 + \langle v_1-v_0,\ldots,v_d-v_0\rangle$, so would not be an affine basis.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Nice answer! Thank you so much. Just one more question! I think that what you said is true for the basis of the projective geometry $PG_{d-1}(F)$ and the action of $PGL_d(F)$ on the set of these bases, too. Am I right? I think that the basis of $PG_{d-1}(F)$ is of the form $\{[v],[v+v_1],[v+v_2],\ldots,[v+v_d]\}$.

Comment: Yes that looks right!